# Can I Automatically append/suffix an image file name with the contents of the 'Tag' meta data?

Tags: filenames

I hope you can help. I am a complete amateur and don't understand anything about scripts and what not. I have all my photos tagged - places, people etc. using the 'Tags' metadata field. I would like to amend the file names of my photo files with that tag so that photos can be found in Amazon Photos (why that don't allow a meta data search I will never know)

I have read through a lot of the stuff here and EXIF keeps coming up, but all seems to be related to dates and times and not the tags field. I was hoping someone could

1. Tell me if that would work for what I need and
2. if you have time, just jot down the best way for me to make it work for the uneducated.

Comment: What exactly is meant by "Tags" here? In what app did you add your tags?

Comment: There are many **Tags** in EXIF meta data. The 'Date taken' tag contains the date the image was taken. The 'Title' tag contains the title. The 'Focal Length' tag contains lens focal length information. The 'Aperture' tag contains the lens aperture used. Etc. Which tag(s) do you want to add to the file name? 'Title'? 'Subject'? 'Key words? Something else? There is no 'Tag' tag.

Comment: most photography ingest programs will offer extensive custom templated filenames using exif, os meta and existing filenames while copying/moving files from one folder to another.

Comment: Hi @Ray and welcome to Photo.SE! The first comment of dandavis is very important: please [edit] your question to indicate in what app you created these tags. Some apps respect standards and write tags/keywords using the appropriate EXIF fields, some apps use some proprietary mechanism, making it (nearly) impossible to re-use those tags outside of that single app.